# scoping mongoid_slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I'm using [mongoid-slug](https://github.com/hakanensari/mongoid-slug) gem  and I have this model:

```
class Board
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
 include Mongoid::Slug

 field :name

 #slug
 slug :name

end
```

I have a controller in root controllers directory with name **boards_controller.rb**

But I have inside controller directory a directory with name **admin** and I have inside other **boards_controller.rb**.

Then for this last controller have a path **controllers/admin/boards_controller.rb**

**I want to use slug only in first controller. In this last controller I don't want to use slug.
How can I do it?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want find by the slug you need do

```
Board.find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

When you want find you Board by his id not his slug you can do :

```
Board.find(params[:id])
```

In path you need do if you want slug :

```
board_url(@board)
```

or without slug

```
 admin_board_url(:id => @board.id)
```

Comment: Hey Thank you it does works fine. How could be for delete method without slug with this code `<%= link_to 'Delete', [:admin, board], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class=>'delete_board' %>`

Comment: The problem was fixed :D with `admin_board_url(:id => board.id)`. Thank you!